# How do I find the amount of energy needed to evaporate water below its boiling point?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

Let's say I have a container filled with water and its surface is in direct contact with air. How much heat/energy do I have to supply to the water such that it evaporates under its boiling point? is there even such a formula? I've looked everywhere, and the resources that I have found just calculates the amount of water (in mm/day) is evaporated, and not the amount of energy needed to evaporate the water under its boiling point.

Sorry if my question seems confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out pan evaporation, been done for many many years. One of the results used to prove Global Dimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you look for is the [Enthalpy of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization). This is temperature dependent and can be found in a steam table (or with one of the steam table calculators)